# Solving $4^{667} ≡ x \pmod{13}$ without Eulers totient theorem or CRT

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Does anyone know any efficient ways to solve this without Euler's Totient Theorem or Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Just find $\text{ord}_{13}(4)$ empirically, which we know exists since $\gcd(4,13)=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As $5*13=65$  we have

$$4^3 \equiv -1 \pmod{13}$$

Even without this observation, you can calculate $4,4^2, 4^3, ... \pmod{13}$ and since there are only at most 12 posibilities you know that the powers must repeat after at most 12 steps. Find the repeating pattern.

**Note:** As you calculate, you can make each number in the sequence $4,4^2, 4^3, ... \pmod{13}$ between $0$ and $12$ which makes the computation simpler.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Ty fixed... You type faster :D

Comment: Why did we do 5*13?

Comment: @Juan I looked at $13, 13+13, 13+13+13,..$ until I got close to a  power of $4$.

Comment: got it. thanks.  (4^3)*(4^222)*4 ≡ ((-1)^222)*4 ≡ 4(mod 13)

Answer (score 3):

Note $13\times 5 =65$ so $64=4^3\equiv -1 \mod 13$. Then $667=3\times 222+1$, so it is all $4=x\mod 13$, and we're done.